# Drawing CountryData groups

Tags: list-manipulation, curated-data, geography

I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious, but I can't draw groups of countries. Here are two countries and two country groups:

```
france = CountryData["France", "Coordinates"] ;
usa = CountryData["United States", "Coordinates"];  
eu = CountryData["EU", "Coordinates"];
africa = CountryData["Africa", "Coordinates"];
```

Swapping the coordinates so that longitude comes before latitude:

```
franceA = Cases[france , {lat_, long_} :> {long, lat}, Infinity];
usaA = Cases[usa, {lat_, long_} :> {long, lat}, Infinity];
euA = Cases[eu, {lat_, long_} :> {long, lat}, Infinity];
africaA = Cases[africa, {lat_, long_} :> {long, lat}, Infinity];
```

They should all plot:

```
Table[Graphics[Line[coords]], 
 {coords, {franceA, usaA, euA, africaA}}]
```

but the groups don't:

[image: error]

And I tried this:

```
Table[
 Graphics[
  Polygon /@ Map[
    GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[#], 
       "Mercator"][[1]] &, {coords}, {2}]], 
 {coords, {france, usa, eu, africa}}]
```

with a similar problem:

[image: error 2]

I'm thinking that two of the lists are the wrong shape or size, but they look OK:

```
Dimensions[#] & /@ 
  {france, usa, eu, africa, franceA, usaA, euA, africaA}

{{2}, {1, 4672, 2}, {27}, {58}, {1110, 2}, {4672, 2}, {18404, 2}, {16082, 2}}
```

I may need some `Flatten`ing magic somewhere...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the problems, as halirutan has already mentioned, is that the patterns are not restrictive enough. `{x_, y_}` will also match `{{dog}, {cat}}`, whereas we want it to only match pairs of numerical coordinates. However, that is not the reason for the error that you're getting (although it makes it harder to fix). As it turns out, you get the same error with your original `eu` and `africa` (before flipping). Why does this happen only with these two and not `france` or `usa`?

Observe that both these are *continents*, which gives us a hint at where the problem lies. The coordinate list structure for countries looks like (pseudocode)

```
{
    {{lat11, lon11}, ..., {lat1N, lon1N}}, (* largest land polygon *)
    {{lat21, lon22}, ..., {lat2M, lon2M}}, (* next largest polygon *)
    ...
}
```

so when you use `Line` to plot them, you're using this definition of [Line](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Line.html):

> `Line[{{pt11, pt12, ...}, {pt21, ...}, ...}]` represents a collection of points

However, the list structure for continents looks like

```
{
    {   (* Country A *)
        {{latA11, lonA11}, ..., {latA1NA, lonA1NA}}, (* largest land polygon of A *)
        {{latA21, lonA22}, ..., {latA2MA, lonA2MA}}, (* next largest polygon of A *)
        ...
    },

    {   (* Country B *)
        {{latB11, lonB11}, ..., {latB1NB, lonB1NB}}, (* largest land polygon of B *)
        {{latB21, lonB22}, ..., {latB2MB, lonB2MB}}, (* next largest polygon of B *)
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

which does not match any valid syntax for `Line`.

---

Let's look at where exactly the problem lies in your `euA`:

```
Table[Graphics[Line@Take[euA, n]] ~Labeled~ n, {n, 5161, 5170, 1}]
```

[image]

```
euA[[5167]] // Short
```

[image]

Element `5167` is a list of lists and not a pair of coordinates as the first 5166 were. And indeed, `Dimensions@euA[[5167]]` returns `{2}`, and as I explained above, the pattern just matched the sublists and flipped them, leaving the coordinates intact.

---

Now coming to plotting `eu`, I don't think `Cases` is the right tool, since it removes all information about how the polygons are grouped. Instead, you can just `Flatten` it appropriately and reverse the coordinates as

```
Graphics[Line@Flatten[eu, 1] /. {lat_?NumericQ, lon_?NumericQ} :> {lon, lat}]
```

[image]

`Line` correctly interprets this as a *collection of lines* and plots disconnected islands, and thus you don't get the crisscrossing of lines across the plot as in halirutan's answer.

Comment: Ah, that's excellent - you've explained exactly what's going on. Many thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You need to ensure that your rule only matches when you have a pair of numeric coordinates:

```
france = CountryData["France", "Coordinates"];
usa = CountryData["United States", "Coordinates"];
eu = CountryData["EU", "Coordinates"];
africa = CountryData["Africa", "Coordinates"];

rule = {lat_?NumericQ, long_?NumericQ} :> {long, lat};
franceA = Cases[france, rule, Infinity];
usaA = Cases[usa, rule, Infinity];
euA = Cases[eu, rule, Infinity];
africaA = Cases[africa, rule, Infinity];

Table[Graphics[Line[coords]], {coords, {franceA, usaA, euA, africaA}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is there any particular reason why you don't use this here:

```
Graphics@CountryData["EU", "Polygon"] /. Polygon :> Line
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Cool, thanks. What's in there that doesn't work like France and USA? I couldn't see anything - I had a look for `MissingValue`... (And there's usually no reason for my odd coding... :)

Comment: I assume the different countries are stored in different point sublists. Therefore, with your code something like this is likely to happen: `Cases[{{{a,b},{c,d}},{{e,f},{g,h}}},{lat_,long_}:>{long,lat},Infinity]`

Comment: @rm-rf I suppose I was fooled by the fact that France worked even though it had two pieces...

Answer (score 4):

Since you're getting only coordinates, you can map `Reverse` instead of using `ReplaceAll`.

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Opacity[0], Polygon@Flatten[Map[Reverse, eu, {-2}], 1]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Unless I missed something, I don't think anyone has pointed out yet that if you use `Line` instead of `Polygon`, you get small gaps in each segment.  For instance there is one where France meets Italy:

[image]

For the rest, I think rm-rf and halirutan have explained it admirably.

Comment: Monte Carlo not being in the EU. - I'd forgotten.